# Plugin for making marquee like text using jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, marquee

In the process of making an old webpage standard compliant, the validator came across a marquee tag... and screamed bloody hell....

Is there any good jquery plugin to achieve the same effect as the marquee tag...? I googled around a bit and found a couple but both involved enhancing the animation of the marquee tag...

Any suggestion is appreciated... Cheers...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JScoller](http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/)

From the site:

> This Autoscroller is Crossbrowser compatible and also w3c compatible, because its don't used marquee.